VS Code Webview Extension - EventListeners not working when dynamically adding elements
I am trying to build Webview extension for VS Code, but I cant make event listeners work reliably when building the view dynamically. The following code is recreating button in runtime (label is changed as expected), but the event handler is not triggered.
This is generally happening when the view is updated by adding new elements and I havent figured out any solution to make this work :/
Is this VS Code bug or am I doing something wrong? Anyone experienced similar issue?
function onClick(e : Event)
{
    //e.stopPropagation();
    const variableToExpandOrCollapse = new ExpandOrCollapseVariable();
    variableToExpandOrCollapse.fullName = "<clicked>";
    liveVariableVsCode.postMessage({command: 'custom/expandOrCollapseVariable',value: variableToExpandOrCollapse});
}

(function () 
{
    liveVariableVsCode = acquireVsCodeApi();

    setInterval(() => 
    {
        const button = document.createElement('button');

        button.addEventListener('click', onClick);      
        button.textContent = "my button" + Math.random().toString();

        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.appendChild(button);
        
        const treeRoot = document.getElementById("treeId");
        
        if (treeRoot.firstChild)
        {
            treeRoot.removeChild(treeRoot.firstChild);
        }
        treeRoot.appendChild(p);

    }, 100);
})();

